# How to handle the "A control is already associated with the element." error message?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, telerik

So I'm making this webpage in ASP.NET and I'm using Telerik to add controls. Basically I've seen this error message a few times now, but they always disappear by accident. This time I want to make myself a script on how to handle these kind of error messages, because let's be honest, they are pretty vague.

I could show you the .aspx page markup, but it's 1854 lines long, including javascript and styling.

```
Uncaught Error: Sys.InvalidOperationException: A control is already associated with the element.
    at Function.Error$create [as create] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:237)
    at Function.Error$invalidOperation [as invalidOperation] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:387)
    at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxManager.Sys$UI$Control (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:5273)
    at Function.Type$initializeBase [as initializeBase] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:737)
    at Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxManager.Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxControl (ScriptResource.axd?d=sF8Y0c2qLAfpveBK9gLo7DYIWpF0kHA4q-Pt9ojt_VJ_ybOgW_Pq9RzyqLJ95IuBuRuNgHRg2lCAJn…:2)
    at Function.Type$initializeBase [as initializeBase] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:737)
    at new Telerik.Web.UI.RadAjaxManager (ScriptResource.axd?d=sF8Y0c2qLAfpveBK9gLo7DYIWpF0kHA4q-Pt9ojt_VJ_ybOgW_Pq9RzyqLJ95IuBuRuNgHRg2lCAJn…:740)
    at Sys$Component$create (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:3811)
    at <anonymous>:2:5
    at Sys$_Application$add_init [as add_init] (ScriptResource.axd?d=D9drwtSJ4hBA6O8UhT6CQhGMLGaPJPBdtRlUsVMy7uq-wvax2qZNzcGY_AK-UZZ7G_ZsBajxk46XcD…:4737)
```

My question would rather be, how do I tackle an error message like this one? Where do I look, what could be possible problems to cause this to happen?

Also, can I perhaps debug on something to figure out what element it's complaining about?

Comment: Based on the supplied information, it is hard to determine the cause of the issue.

Comment: I agree, but there have to be common reason why this error occurs. Like I said, I'd give all the code, but I doubt I'm able to paste it all in here and it'd take me an hour to cut out all the confidential stuff.

Comment: Take your time. give us only the revelant part. Please do not paste all the code. In fact if you can reproduce the code in a [mcve] you are half ways from finding the solution.